# Scala's || and | operators

Tags: scala, if-statement

I noticed something today. Scala has the usual OR `||`, but also the `|`.

My first thought was that the `|` was a strict OR. So `true | true`, will evaluate to `false`.
But,

```
val x = true
x: Boolean = true
val y = true
y: Boolean = true
x || y
res4: Boolean = true
x | y
res5: Boolean = true
```

What is the `|` operator for? Is it just an alias?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As in Java, the single `&` and `|` operators do the same thing as their usual versions but without [short-circuiting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

As an example, consider the expression `true || isNice()`. The method will never be called because `true || x` is always true and the compiler (and runtime) knows that. If you insist on all parts of a boolean expression to be evaluated, you have to use `&` or `|`.

Edit: For completeness, Scala also uses the `|` for alternative patterns in pattern matching. This is copied from the language reference:

> 8.1.11 Pattern Alternatives
>   Syntax:
>   Pattern ::= Pattern1 { ‘|’ Pattern1 }
>
> A pattern alternative p1 | ... | pn consists of a number of alternative patterns
>   pi
>   . All alternative patterns are type checked with the expected type of the pattern.
>   They may no bind variables other than wildcards. The alternative pattern matches
>   a value v if at least one its alternatives matches v.

Comment: I know this is a different question, but does java have a strict `OR`?

Comment: It does indeed: `^`. `true ^ true == false`. Also known as XOR

Comment: Reference: http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/12-the-scala-standard-library.html#class-boolean